# Express: how to pass variables to mounted middleware

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, express

I've just started to play around with Expressjs and I'm wondering how to pass variables to mounted middleware/sub application. In the following example, I'd like the config object passed to my /blog/index

in app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//...
var config = {}
//...
app.use('/blog', require('./blog/index')
```

in /blog/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
app = module.exports = express();

app.use(express.static(...
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //handle the req and res
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two options here:

1. Since your `blog` app is an express application, you can use `app.set` and `app.get`. E.g.

   ```
    blog = require('./blog/index');
    blog.set('var1', value1);
    blog.set('var2', value2); 
    ...
    app.use('/blog', blog);
   ```

   And in `blog/index.js` use `app.get('var1')` to get the value of `var1`.
2. You can wrap the `blog` express application in another function that accepts configuration parameters (much like the `static` middleware accepts a directory name) and returns the configured application. Let me know if you want an example.

**EDIT:** Example for the 2nd option

app.js would look like this:

```
var blog = require('./blog/index');
...
var config = {};
app.use('/blog', blog(config));
```

and /blog/index.js like that:

```
var express = require('express')

module.exports = function(config) {
    var app = express();
    // configure the app and do some other stuffs here
    // ...

    return app;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm now wondering why I haven't figured out the 1st option myself. Anyway, yes please if you can provide a short example for the option 2 that seems to look better.

Comment: It's now working with the 2nd option ... marvellous. Thanks again for your support.

Comment: @Ludohen: Why don't you go ahead and edit the answer to add a short example for option #2? Or add another answer to your question. For future reference :)